# apm/npm serialport fail to load on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, atom-editor, node-serialport

I'm building an Atom plugin that need to use the serial port.
I've `npm install --save serialport` and it seem to work but when I run it on Windows 10 machine I'm getting the error #1 listed bellow.
If I delete `node_modules/serialport` directory and do `apm install` I'm getting  error #2 which is a node-pre-gyn compilation error.

1. How to fix this?
2. Why is the difference between `npm` and `apm`?

#### Error #1

```
Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\C:\Users\idoran\github\arduino\node_modules\serialport\build\Release\serialport.node
    at Error (native)
    at process.module.(anonymous function) (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:158:20)
    at process.module.(anonymous function) (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:158:20)
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:158:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:440:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:158:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (C:\Users\idoran\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.10.0\resources\app.asar\src\native-compile-cache.js:50:27)
    at bindings (C:\Users\idoran\github\arduino\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\idoran\github\arduino\node_modules\serialport\lib\bindings.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\idoran\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.10.0\resources\app.asar\src\native-compile-cache.js:103:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value [as .js] (C:\Users\idoran\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.10.0\resources\app.asar\src\compile-cache.js:208:21)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (C:\Users\idoran\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.10.0\resources\app.asar\src\native-compile-cache.js:50:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\idoran\github\arduino\node_modules\serialport\lib\serialport.js:12:25)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\idoran\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.10.0\resources\app.asar\src\native-compile-cache.js:103:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value [as .js] (C:\Users\idoran\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.10.0\resources\app.asar\src\compile-cache.js:208:21)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (C:\Users\idoran\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.10.0\resources\app.asar\src\native-compile-cache.js:50:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\idoran\github\arduino\lib\master.js:9:10)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\idoran\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.10.0\resources\app.asar\src\native-compile-cache.js:103:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value [as .js] (C:\Users\idoran\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.10.0\resources\app.asar\src\compile-cache.js:208:21)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
```

#### Error #2

```
Installing modules failed
> serialport@4.0.1 install C:\Users\idoran\github\arduino\node_modules\serialport
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number. [C:\Users\idoran\github\arduino\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. [C:\Users\idoran\github\arduino\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]


Failed to execute 'C:\Users\idoran\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.10.0\resources\app\apm\bin\node.exe C:\Users\idoran\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.10.0\resources\app\apm\bin\\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\idoran\github\arduino\node_modules\serialport\build\Release\serialport.node --module_name=serialport --module_path=C:\Users\idoran\github\arduino\node_modules\serialport\build\Release' (1)

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport/releases/download/4.0.1/serialport-v4.0.1-electron-v0.37-win32-ia32.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for serialport@4.0.1 and electron@0.37.8 (electron-v0.37 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\idoran\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.10.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\idoran\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.10.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\idoran\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.10.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\idoran\\github\\arduino\\node_modules\\serialport\\build\\Release\\serialport.node" "--module_name=serialport" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\idoran\\github\\arduino\\node_modules\\serialport\\build\\Release"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\idoran\github\arduino\node_modules\serialport
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Users\idoran\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.10.0\resources\app\apm\bin\node.exe C:\Users\idoran\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.10.0\resources\app\apm\bin\\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\idoran\github\arduino\node_modules\serialport\build\Release\serialport.node --module_name=serialport --module_path=C:\Users\idoran\github\arduino\node_modules\serialport\build\Release' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\idoran\github\arduino\node_modules\serialport\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\idoran\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.10.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\idoran\\github\\arduino\\node_modules\\serialport\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\idoran\github\arduino\node_modules\serialport
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.5
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.29
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\idoran\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.10.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\idoran\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.10.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "C:\\Users\\idoran\\.atom\\.apm\\.apmrc" "--userconfig" "C:\\Users\\idoran\\.atom\\.apmrc" "install" "--runtime=electron" "--target=0.37.8" "--arch=ia32" "--msvs_version=2015"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! serialport@4.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the serialport@4.0.1 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the serialport package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs serialport
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls serialport
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\idoran\github\arduino\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild) to build native modules with specific node/Atom version. This would ensure that module is built and installed at the location Atom expects it to find.

I used this approach for using node-serialport in an Electron project.

Edit :

electron-rebuild depends on availability of VC++ compiler (cl.exe). Ensure that cl.exe is installed and is on path. Visual Studio does not install c++ by default, so choose vc++ as option during setup.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/24/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers/

Comment: Did you use it on a Windows machine?

Comment: I had almost the same problem (compile node serialport  to work with Electron / Atom on Windows 10 64 bit). electorn-rebuild resolved that issue.  Let me know if this does not work for you. I can provide more specific steps.

Comment: installing electron-rebuild fail with the same error serialport failed with - error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Do you have visual C++ installed on this system ?  Visual Studio 2015 doesn't install C++ by default. You have to rerun the setup, select Modify and then check Programming Language -> C++

Comment: If VC++ is installed, pls ensure that cl.exe is in the path before running electron-rebuild

Comment: I've try to install Win10 SDK but it didn't had cl.exe. I'm installing Visual Studio Express 2015 for Desktop which should have C++

Comment: Visual studio does not have C++ by default. You need to choose options to install c++ during setup.    https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/24/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers/

Comment: Also add --msvs_version=2015 to lrectron-rebuild so that it can setup compile options.

Comment: Installing Visual Studio Express 2015 for Desktop  and adding the directory of cl.exe to PATH env-var solve the issue. Now using `apm install` successfully install `serialport` on Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Great, I will update answer to include these details.

Comment: I meant that eventually I didn't need `electron-rebuild` :) Simple `apm install` worked.

Comment: Both commands do the same thing under the hood (download source files and compile). Same steps would make electron-rebuild work as well.